# $\ell$ is a circle that lies in the intersection of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and plane $x+y=0$, calculate : $\int_\ell xyz\,ds$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\ell$ is a circle that lies in the intersection of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and plane $x+y=0$, calculate $ \displaystyle \int_\ell xyz\,ds.$

FIrst I have started with parametrizing intersection:

$x=-y$; I replaced this in sphere equation and got an ellipse: $2y^2+z^2=1$, parametrized it as follows: $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \cos t, z=\sin t$, and since $x=-y$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \cos t$ ($0\leq t \leq 2\pi$); but when I solve the integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2} \cos^2t\sin t \, dt$$ I get $0$...

Is the parametrization okay?

Comment: Of course integrate $ds$ not $dt$

Comment: Note that $ds= \left\| r'\left(t\right)\right\| dt$. It seems like you forgot the term $\left\| r'\left(t\right)\right\|$.

Comment: I haven't it just equals to $1$, if I understood you.

Comment: So compute using your parametrization that $ds = dt$, and you are finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand is an odd function of $z$

$$\int xy(-z) \,ds= -\int (xyz)\,ds$$

and the curve of intersection has $z$ symmetry, i.e.

$$x^2+y^2+(-z)^2=1 \:\cap\:x+y=0 \iff x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \:\cap\:x+y=0$$

Therefore the integral is $0$ by odd symmetry.